# Removing non-integer elements from list on last level

Tags: list-manipulation

The list I have looks approximately like this:

```
{
{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}},
{{0,0,0},{4,2,1},{Error,NotFound,7}},
{{NotFound,If[1<=NotFound,0,3],4},{3,2,1},{NotFound,2,1}}
}
```

How can I remove non-integer values at the last level of this list?

Comment: does this give what you need: `Replace[data, Except[_Integer | _List] -> Nothing, All]` or, alternatively, `DeleteCases[data, Except[_Integer | _List], All]`?

Comment: @kglr unfortunately no. It gives me a list that looks something like this: ``` {{{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1}, {1}, {0, 1}, {1}, {1}, {0, 
   1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1}, {1}, {0, 1}, {0, 
   1}, {1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1}, {1}, {0, 1} ```

Comment: 100xln2,  did you use `data = {
{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}},
{{0,0,0},{4,2,1},{Error,NotFound,7}},
{{NotFound,If[1<=NotFound,0,3],4},{3,2,1},{NotFound,2,1}}
}`?

Comment: @kglr no, I used the data im working with. If You want, here is a excerpt: ```...{{1/50, 1/
   6 If[1 >= "NotFound", 1 - "NotFound", nCars + 1 - "NotFound"], 1/
  7}, {1/25, 0, 1/7}, {3/50, 1/3, 1/7}, {2/25, 1/3, 1/7}, {1/10, 1/3, 
  1/7}, {3/25, 1/3, 1/7}, {7/50, 1/2, 1/7}, {4/25, 1/2, 1/7}, {9/50, 
  0, 1/7},....```

Comment: could you try `DeleteCases[data, Except[_?NumericQ | _List], All]`?

Comment: @kglr ahh yes, the last one ```DeleteCases[data, Except[_?NumericQ | _List], All]``` has worked. Thank You.

Comment: `Replace[data, Except[_?NumericQ | _List] -> Nothing, All]` should also work.

Comment: The word 'Level' has predefined meaning and usage in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[data, Except[_?NumericQ | _List], All]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {4, 2, 1}, {7}},  
>  {{4}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 1}}}
> ```

```
Replace[data, Except[_?NumericQ | _List] -> Nothing, All]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {4, 2, 1}, {7}},   
>  {{4}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 1}}}
> ```